# How can I map an action for option (Mac keyboard) up for a JTextField?

Tags: java, macos, swing, awt, jtextfield

Looks like option up can be caught only with AWT (i.e., adding key listener). Is there a way to do it without having to mess around with AWT?

Comment: Did you check the documentation for `KeyBinding` available [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html)?

Comment: Yes, I did. Multiple times.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Mac OS X UI delegate for `JTextField` does not bind <kbd>alt</kbd><kbd>↑</kbd> to any [`Action`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/action.html). You are free to bind the combination to any action you choose. As shown in [*How to Use Key Bindings*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html), the example below binds <kbd>alt</kbd><kbd>↑</kbd> to the existing `"caret-begin-line"` defined for `JTextField`, which moves the caret to the beginning of the line.

```
final JTextField jtf = new JTextField("Test");
jtf.getInputMap().put(
    KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_UP, KeyEvent.ALT_MASK),
    "caret-begin-line");
```

More examples may be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=jtextfield%20getInputMap). As shown in the key binding utility cited [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4299950/230513), `JTextField` binds the following `WHEN_FOCUSED` actions by name to the indicated key(s).

```
beep
caret-backward                LEFT, KP_LEFT, ctrl B
caret-begin                   ctrl P, meta UP, meta KP_UP, HOME
caret-begin-line              KP_UP, ctrl A, UP, meta KP_LEFT, meta LEFT
caret-begin-paragraph
caret-begin-word
caret-down
caret-end                     ctrl N, END, meta KP_DOWN, ctrl V, meta DOWN
caret-end-line                DOWN, meta KP_RIGHT, ctrl E, meta RIGHT, KP_DOWN
caret-end-paragraph
caret-end-word
caret-forward                 RIGHT, ctrl F, KP_RIGHT
caret-next-word               alt KP_RIGHT, alt RIGHT
caret-previous-word           alt KP_LEFT, alt LEFT
caret-up
copy
copy-to-clipboard             meta C, COPY
cut
cut-to-clipboard              CUT, meta X
default-typed
delete-next                   DELETE, ctrl D
delete-next-word              alt DELETE
delete-previous               BACK_SPACE, ctrl H
delete-previous-word          alt BACK_SPACE, ctrl W
dump-model
insert-break
insert-content
insert-tab
notify-field-accept           ENTER
page-down
page-up
paste
paste-from-clipboard          meta V, PASTE
requestFocus
select-all                    meta A
select-line
select-paragraph
select-word
selection-backward            shift LEFT, shift KP_LEFT
selection-begin               shift meta KP_UP, shift meta UP, shift HOME
selection-begin-line          shift UP, shift meta KP_LEFT, shift KP_UP, shift meta LEFT
selection-begin-paragraph
selection-begin-word
selection-down
selection-end                 shift meta DOWN, shift meta KP_DOWN, shift END
selection-end-line            shift meta KP_RIGHT, shift DOWN, shift KP_DOWN, shift meta RIGHT
selection-end-paragraph
selection-end-word
selection-forward             shift KP_RIGHT, shift RIGHT
selection-next-word           shift alt KP_RIGHT, shift alt RIGHT
selection-page-down           shift PAGE_DOWN
selection-page-left           shift meta PAGE_UP
selection-page-right          shift meta PAGE_DOWN
selection-page-up             shift PAGE_UP
selection-previous-word       shift alt LEFT, shift alt KP_LEFT
selection-up
set-read-only
set-writable
toggle-componentOrientation   shift ctrl O
unselect                      meta BACK_SLASH
```

Comment: I'm more than disappointed in the documentation. Perhaps that's why there are so many conflicting answers posted at SO regarding this concept.