# Java: Adding a keyListener to an already visible JFrame

Tags: java, multithreading, jframe, sleep, keylistener

Again...  I have another issue with the keyListener and the JFrame.  I want to be able to add a keyListener to the JFrame while the JFrame is visible.  My problem is that when I try this, the keyListener doesn't respond.  Here is my code:

```
public JFrame frame = new JFrame("JFrame Test");

public static void main(String[]args) {
    new JFrameTest();
}

public JFrameTest() {
    frame.setSize(100, 100);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setResizable(false);
    frame.setVisible(true);
    try {
        Thread.sleep(1000);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    frame.add(new space());
    frame.validate();
    frame.repaint();
}

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class space extends JPanel {
    public space() {
        setFocusable(true);
        addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
                System.out.println("Mouse Pressed!");
            }

            public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
                System.out.println("Mouse Released!");
            }
        });
        addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {
            public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
                System.out.println("Key Pressed!");
            }

            public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
                System.out.println("Key Released!");
            }
        });
    }
    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.fillRect(0, 0, frame.getWidth() / 2, frame.getHeight() / 2);
        repaint();
    }
}
```

I delay the adding of the keyListener to represent the time the user would take to press a button which would, in turn, activate the keyListener.  I know the sleep is not the issue because in my large scale project I have the same issue but it is after I press a button after waiting x amount of time to load up the game space.  I do not know if I am repainting and validating correctly but no one seems to have this issue.  Any help would be appreciated.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is probably related to an error in your use of [the focus subsystem](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/focus.html).

In [this StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2135223/obtaining-focus-on-a-jpanel), David shows that although the panel is set up correctly,

> ... the panel isn't asking for focus. Try using myPanel.requestFocus();

In addition, [the Java Tutorial on `KeyListener`s](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/keylistener.html) mentions that

> key events are fired by **the component with the keyboard focus** when the user presses or releases keyboard keys

(emphasis added).

So, instead of using `add(new space())`, you should:

```
space s = new space();
add(s);
s.requestFocus();
```

and that should fix your problem.

Comment: Very nicely answered and thank you for taking the time to find that.  Thanks!