# Java Key Bindings output to console on key press

Tags: java, swing, paintcomponent, key-bindings, thread-sleep

I'm trying to make a program that moves a rectangle around the screen when the arrow keys are pressed. At the moment I'm working on keybindings, after KeyListeners proved to be unreliable and fairly useless. Before trying to make the rectangle move, I'm just trying to make the press of the Up arrow key trigger `System.out.println("Up key pressed!")`, simply to make sure my KeyBindings are actually working. The problem is, they aren't. I'm following [this](http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/245148-java-key-binding-tutorial-and-demo-program/) tutorial, which is a little different from what I'm trying to achieve but should still teach me how to use key bindings. Why does the KeyBinding not work?

Code:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;


public class GamePanel extends JPanel implements Runnable{

    boolean isRunning = true;
    int count = 0;
    Thread t;
    static int rectX = 250;
    static int rectY = 250;
    Action upAction;
    Action downAction;
    Action leftAction;
    Action rightAction;

    public GamePanel()
    {
        upAction = new UpAction();
        t = new Thread(this);
        t.run();
        /*downAction = new DownAction();
        leftAction = new LeftAction();
        rightAction = new RightAction();*/
        this.getInputMap().put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("UP"), "upMotion");
        this.getActionMap().put("upMotion",upAction);

    }
    public void run()
    {
        loop();
    }
    public void loop()
    {
        if(isRunning)
        {
            Thread t = Thread.currentThread();
            try
            {
            t.sleep(5);
            }
            catch(InterruptedException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            repaint();
        }

    }
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
    {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        count += 1;
        g.drawString(Integer.toString(count), 10, 10);
        g.drawRect(rectX, rectY, 50, 50);
        loop();
    }
    static class UpAction extends AbstractAction
    {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
        {
            System.out.println("Up key pressed!");
            rectY++;
        }
    }
}
```

Main JFrame code:

```
import javax.swing.*;

public class MainFrame{

    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Space Invaders");
    GamePanel gamepanel = new GamePanel();

    public MainFrame()
    {
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setResizable(false);
        frame.setSize(500,500);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.add(gamepanel);
    }
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        new MainFrame();
    }


}
```

Comment: where is your main? cant run this code.

Comment: @kai My main code simply makes a JFrame and adds this class to it as a JPanel

Comment: That loop is *bad*. It will halt the current thread which called the constructor, so you can't have a running Panel anywhere (except if you export `this` from constructor). Try running the `loop` method in a new  Thread.

Comment: add your main code, so i can run it.

Comment: Is the frame even visible? you create a `new GamePanel();` in your frame (and this initialization will be called just before frame constructor) but your GamePanel constructor halts the current thread, so you should't see anything. Am i right?

Comment: @kajacx I've edited my code. And no, even before I edited I still saw a rapidly increasing number and a rectangle be drawn

Comment: 1. Thread.sleep(5); is under latency for most of todays Native OS's, 2. Thread.sleep(5); block EDT until if(isRunning) ended

Comment: @mKorbel I don't understand. Can you explain further?

Comment: loop(); is invoked from 1. all mouse and key events, 2. methods implemented in API, 3. most important from endless cloning invoked by repaint() inside if(isRunning)

Comment: @mKorbel Yes I want it to be endlessly invoked; that works as a game loop

Comment: short answer 1. use Swing Timer, forgot for idea to call recrusive loop(); == creating endless, un_manageble loop, 3. delay (minimal value) should be 25/33/50 miliseconds, depends of Native OS and GPU

Comment: Yes I want it to be endlessly invoked; == for this reason is there loop, but calling loop(); from public void paintComponent(Graphics g) multiply this crazy idea :-)

Comment: @mKorbel Changing the delay to 25 worked! Thank you!

Comment: @mKorbel And...after I ran it and then closed it, I ran it again and it stopped working.

Comment: similair question are asked 3-5 times per day, you can increasing your chances by click to paintComponent or KeyBindings tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The whole problem was that your panel didn't have focus, and thusly couldn't recieve any input events. After following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2137112/1003886) answer, adding 2 lines solved the problem:

```
public GamePanel() {
    ...
    setFocusable(true); //add this anywhere in this constructor 
}

public MainFrame() {
    ...
    frame.add(gamepanel);
    gamepanel.requestFocusInWindow();
    //add this after adding the panel to your frame and making it visible
}
```

**EDIT:**

Also, you code has several bugs:

- Moving up should be `y--`, since top-left corner has coordinates [0,0] and the `x` axis is going to right and `y` is going **down** (unlike in math class)
- You should *never* call `Thread.sleep()` inside `paint()` method, since that method has to be as fast as possible.
- You are "starting" a new thread using `thread.run()`, use `thread.start()` instead, that will acctually start a new thread instead of just calling the `run` method in current thread.
- Change the `if` to `while` in your `loop` method, also remove the `loop` call from the `paint` method to solve previous two mistakes.

These are not to criticise you (everyone was starting at some point) but to help you.

Comment: After mKorbel's suggestion of changing the Thread.sleep() delay to 25, the Keybindings worked without this. They are however inconsistent

Comment: Do I have to use `public void start(){...}` or will the call to `run()` start the thread?

Comment: Google "java thread run vs start" and pick any link you want... :3

Comment: KeyBindings has setting for Focus implemented in API by default, then everything about Focus aren't answer to OPs question

Comment: Thanks for your help. I can move a rectangle around a screen now!! *Achievement intensifies*