# MouseListener not getting detected

Tags: java, swing, awt, mouselistener

I have a `JPanel` (the grid), nested inside the main `JFrame`. I am trying to set a `Mouselistener` on the grid & report the event to the main frame.

**App.java** *(Entry point)*

```
public class App {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                new MainBoard("Tic Swing Toe");
            }
        });
    }
}
```

**MainBoard.java** *(The main container, the **controller**)*

```
public class MainBoard extends JFrame {

    public static final int WINDOW_MIN_WIDTH = 800;
    public static final int WINDOW_MIN_HEIGHT = 700;

    private HeaderPanel mHeaderPanel; // The header panel
    private BoardPanel mBoardPanel; // The game board panel

    public MainBoard(String windowTitle) {
        // Set window title
        super(windowTitle);

        setMinimumSize(new Dimension(WINDOW_MIN_WIDTH, WINDOW_MIN_HEIGHT));
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setContentPane(new TilePanel());
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        pack();
        setVisible(true);

        // Setup components
        initGUI();

        // Setup listeners on child components
        setupChildListeners();
    }

    /**
     * Setup the GUI components
     */
    private void initGUI() {
        mHeaderPanel = new HeaderPanel();
        mBoardPanel = new BoardPanel();

        add(mHeaderPanel, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        add(mBoardPanel, BorderLayout.WEST);
    }

    /**
     * Sets listeners on child components
     */
    private void setupChildListeners() {
        mBoardPanel.setHoverListener((x, y) -> System.out.println(x + " - " + y));
    }

    /**
     * The background of the application
     */
    class TilePanel extends JPanel {

        private BufferedImage mTile;

        public TilePanel() {
            try {
                // Read image from URL, could change it to disk file
                mTile = ImageIO.read(new URL("http://turbo.designwoop.com/uploads/2012/03/01_free_subtle_textures_apple_ios_linen_texture.jpg"));
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);

            Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();
            int tileWidth = mTile.getWidth();
            int tileHeight = mTile.getHeight();
            for (int y = 0; y < getHeight(); y += tileHeight) {
                for (int x = 0; x < getWidth(); x += tileWidth) {
                    g2d.drawImage(mTile, x, y, this);
                }
            }
            g2d.dispose();
        }
    }
}
```

**BoardPanel.java** *(The JPanel containing the grid, which I'm interested in)*

```
public class BoardPanel extends JPanel {

    public static final int BOARD_BORDER_RADIUS = 20;
    public static final int CELL_MARGIN = BOARD_BORDER_RADIUS / 2;
    public static final int CELL_SIZE = 120;
    public static final int BOARD_WIDTH = CELL_SIZE * 3 + CELL_MARGIN * 4;
    public static final int BOARD_HEIGHT = CELL_SIZE * 3 + CELL_MARGIN * 4;

    // The hover listener that shall report to the 
    private CellHoverListener mHoverListener; 

    public void setHoverListener(CellHoverListener listener) {
        mHoverListener = listener;
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);

        addMouseListener(new BoardMouseListener());
    }

    // A custom MouseListener
    class BoardMouseListener implements MouseListener {

        @Override
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) { }

        @Override
        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) { }

        @Override
        public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) { }

        @Override
        public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
            if(mHoverListener != null)
                mHoverListener.onCellHover(e.getX(), e.getY());
        }

        @Override
        public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) { }
    }

    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        return new Dimension(BOARD_WIDTH, BOARD_HEIGHT);
    }
}
```

**HeaderPanel.java** (The header containing the 2 text lines)

```
public class HeaderPanel extends JPanel {

    public static final String HEADER_TEXT = "Pure Tic Tac Toe Java - AI";
    public static final String SMALL_HEADER_TEXT =
            "The only game where you are the champion if it's a draw";

    // TODO: figure out a way to fill the whole header dynamically
    public static final int HEADER_WIDTH = 1366; // temporary solution
    public static final int HEADER_HEIGHT = 100;

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);

        // Draw the dark blue rectangle
        g.drawRect(0, 0, HEADER_WIDTH, HEADER_HEIGHT);
        g.setColor(new Color(33, 33, 33, 240)); // Dark blue
        g.fillRect(0, 0, HEADER_WIDTH, HEADER_HEIGHT);

        // Draw the first line of text
        g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        FontMetrics fm = g.getFontMetrics();
        Rectangle2D header = fm.getStringBounds(HEADER_TEXT, g);
        int x = (this.getWidth() - (int) header.getWidth()) / 2;
        int y = (this.getHeight() - (int) header.getHeight()) / 4 + fm.getAscent();
        g.drawString(HEADER_TEXT, x, y);

        // Draw the second line of text
        fm = g.getFontMetrics();
        Rectangle2D miniHeader = fm.getStringBounds(SMALL_HEADER_TEXT, g);
        x = (this.getWidth() - (int) miniHeader.getWidth()) / 2;
        y = (this.getHeight() - (int) miniHeader.getHeight()) * 3 / 4 + fm.getAscent();
        g.setColor(new Color(44, 170, 231, 250));
        g.drawString(SMALL_HEADER_TEXT, x, y);
    }

    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        return new Dimension(HEADER_WIDTH, HEADER_HEIGHT);
    }
}
```

**CellHoverListener.java**

```
public interface CellHoverListener {
    void onCellHover(int x, int y);
}
```

### Final Result:

[image: Result]

### The problem

is that the **hover** events are not detected at all. I tried to set a `MouseListener` directly on the `BoardPanel`, but same old behavior.

How can I correctly setup a *listener* on *mouse events* in this case?

Comment: Have you requested focus for the JPanel? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2135223/obtaining-focus-on-a-jpanel

Comment: Added it, didn't make any difference. (I'm not sure where & when to call it.)

Comment: Why are you adding a `MouseListener` inside `paintComponent`? This method is supposed to contain paint-only calculations and return fast. It also means that you are adding a new one each time you paint.

Comment: @user1803551 Where should I call it ?

Comment: Where you set up the components. I'm still going over the code but that popped up like a sore thumb :)

Comment: I would do it in `initGUI`. Call `setFocusable(true);` for the panel you want and then `requestFocus();` for the same one. This is for the focus, not about the paintComponent thing.

Comment: What do you mean by "hover" events? Just movement inside the panel's area?

Comment: I want to **detect every single move inside**, yes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your *main* problem with detecting movement events is that you are not assigning a `MouseMotionListener`:

For example, create a constructor for you panel with:

```
public BoardPanel() {

    BoardMouseListener bml = new BoardMouseListener();
    addMouseListener(bml);
    addMouseMotionListener(bml);
}
```

or wherever you set up your components if you don't want a constructor. Then `@Override` methods for whichever events you want to detect:

```
class BoardMouseListener extends MouseAdapter {

    @Override
    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {

        System.out.println(e.getX() + " - " + e.getY());
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) {

        System.out.println(e.getX() + " - " + e.getY());
    }
}
```

Your other problems are:

- Calling `addMouseListener` inside `paintComponent`. Each time the component is painted you are creating and registering a new listener. This is bad.
- `setVisible` should be called only after you finish setting up all your components.
- Use `extends MouseAdapter`instead of `implements MouseListener` if you don't need to override all of its methods. If you press a button during the movement it won't be "recorded" since this is now a dragging event - use the apprropriate method.

Comment: I appreciate it,  really. I would have accepted your answer if you answered before @whiskey , cuz his answer made me realise that I wasn't setting a **motion listener** which was what I needed.

Comment: @Sparta No problem, but it's a bit funny that his answer doesn't actually contain the solution :)

Comment: @Sparta Yeah, I just asked him to add the solution to his answer. People expect the solution to be there and not in the comments.

Comment: Marked your answer as the **most correct & better** one, because you are **providing much more details & infos** that didn't just helped me out with the problem that this question concerns, but it helped in many other ways.

Answer (score 2):

First, remove `addMouseListener()` from `paintComponent()`.  Note that `paintComponent()` is called repeatedly -- and I'm sure you weren't intending to keep adding new mouse listeners on each `repaint()`.

```
protected void paintComponent(final Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
}
```

Add your listener in a constructor or some kind of `initGUI()` call:

```
public BoardPanel() {
    addMouseListener(new BoardMouseListener());
}
```

Add a debugging statement here.  You'll see that it is indeed being called.

```
public void mouseEntered(final MouseEvent e) {
    System.out.println(e);
    if (mHoverListener != null) {
        mHoverListener.onCellHover(e.getX(), e.getY());
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I tried it, but **it does not log every movement** inside. I need to move the mouse out of the grid & move it in again in order to trigger the listener.

Comment: @Sparta That's because it's `mouseEntered` only.  Do the same thing with a `MouseMotionListener `and `mouseMoved`.  You'll get every mouse move.

Comment: Since your answer was accepted, you might actually want to contain the solution with `MouseMotionListener` you hint at in your comment in your answer. Right now your answer is just some notes on the OP's code without a fix.