# Moving an object in Java (KeyPressed)

Tags: java, keypress, keylistener

For my project in school we have to make a game.

I'm trying to make an object move with the arrow keys but nothing happens if I run it and press one of the keys.

Have I maybe implemented the `addKeyListener(this);` in the wrong spot?

```
package VoorbeeldSpel;

import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.event.*;


import javax.swing.*;

public class PlayPanel extends JPanel implements ActionListener, KeyListener {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 584263623777101573 L;
    final static String IMAGE_FOLDER = "images/";
    final static String FILE_FOLDER = "files/";

    private Timer spelTimer = new Timer(50, this); // elke 1000 milliseconden zal een event gelanceerd worden

    private JButton menuKnop;
    private MijnProject mainVenster;


    MusicPlayer music;
    private Image ninjaImage;
    private Image BackgroundImage;

    public int pos_x, pos_y;
    public int v_x, v_y;

    private String inputText = "";

    public PlayPanel(MijnProject mainVenster) {
        this.mainVenster = mainVenster;

        menuKnop = new JButton("Menu");
        menuKnop.addActionListener(this);

        this.add(new JLabel("We are playing ... "));
        this.add(menuKnop);


        addKeyListener(this);

        // Music player laden
        music = new MusicPlayer("nyancat-loop.wav", true);


        // Prentjes laden
        ninjaImage = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource(IMAGE_FOLDER + "ninja.png")).getImage();
        BackgroundImage = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource(IMAGE_FOLDER + "Backgroundmenu.jpg")).getImage();

        spelTimer.start(); // hier starten we de gameloop
    }

    // we gaan init aanroepen nadat we dit JPanel aan het frame hebben toegevoegd
    // op dit moment zijn de hoogte en breedte van het panel bepaald en kunnen we de pos_x en pos_y variabelen initialiseren als het midden van het scherm
    public void init() {
        addKeyListener(this);
        v_x = ;
        v_y = 0;
        pos_x = getWidth() / 2;
        pos_y = getHeight() / 2;
        addKeyListener(this);
    }
    public void gameloop() {

        pos_x += v_x;
        pos_y += v_y;
        repaint();

    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);

        g.drawImage(BackgroundImage, this.getWidth() / 50, this.getHeight() / 50, mainVenster.getWidth(), mainVenster.getHeight(), this);
        g.drawImage(ninjaImage, pos_x, pos_y, 60, 60, this);

        g.drawChars(inputText.toCharArray(), 0, inputText.length(), 25, getHeight() / 2);
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
        if (ae.getSource() == menuKnop) {
            mainVenster.switchPanel();
            music.stop();
            spelTimer.stop(); // stoppen van het spel

        } else if (ae.getSource() == spelTimer) {

            gameloop();
            addKeyListener(this);
            System.out.println("De volgende stap van het spel wordt uitgevoerd...");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
        switch (e.getKeyCode()) {
            case KeyEvent.VK_UP:
                v_x = 0;
                v_y = -5;
            case KeyEvent.VK_DOWN:
                v_x = 0;
                v_y = 5;
            case KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT:
                v_x = 5;
                v_y = 0;
            case KeyEvent.VK_LEFT:
                v_x = -5;
                v_y = 0;
        }

        repaint();
    }

    @Override
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
        int Keycode = e.getKeyCode();
        switch (Keycode) {
            case KeyEvent.VK_UP:
                v_x = 0;
                v_y = 0;
            case KeyEvent.VK_DOWN:
                v_x = 0;
                v_y = 0;
            case KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT:
                v_x = 0;
                v_y = 0;
            case KeyEvent.VK_LEFT:
                v_x = 0;
                v_y = 0;
        }
        repaint();
    }
}
```

Comment: I doubt you need to add key listener on each loop iteration, that's too many listeners (or if internal code is sane, it will just ignore your pleas and have only one listener anyway).

Answer (score 1):

This is probably because `KeyListener` only receives a `KeyEvent` if the component is focused. There are some suggestions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2135223/obtaining-focus-on-a-jpanel) which might solve the problem for you; however I don't recommend them because they're kludgy. Another kludgy solution that I don't see over there is to add the key listener to the `JFrame` and then using `setFocusable(false)` and `setFocusTraversalKeysEnabled(false)` on any components which might steal the focus away. Key listeners are especially tricky if you're adding other components, like `JButton` and `JTextField` to your UI.

A better solution is to use Swing key bindings which don't have problems handling the focus system. [Here's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15290035/key-bindings-vs-key-listeners-in-java) a Q&A which explains some of the motivation for them, and there's a [tutorial here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html). You can use the `WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW` flag to guarantee that the key bindings always fire regardless of which component has the focus.

Comment: thank you so much for your answer, but as i was fooling around trying to figure out how to solve the problem i saw something called this.requestFocusable(); . This did the trick for me. But still thank you very much for the time you took to help me.

Comment: Yes, which is one of the solutions I don't recommend. If, for example, you added a JButton to the frame and somebody clicks it, the JPanel will lose the focus and stop sending key events again.