# Switching JPanels causing keyListener to fail

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel, keylistener

I am coding a small game and want to have a start screen that switches to the game. I am able to switch JPanels, but after I do, the keyListener I have implemented in said new JPanel is not doing anything. I know that the new JPanel works alone because I have tested it. Here is my code:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;
import java.util.Random;
import javax.swing.*;
@SuppressWarnings("serial")

public class ADGame extends JPanel implements ActionListener, KeyListener{
 Timer t = new Timer(2, this);


    private static ImageIcon rocket;


    private ImageIcon asteroid;


    private ImageIcon bullet;
    private static JLabel rocketlabel;


    private JLabel ast1;


    private JLabel ast2;


    private JLabel ast3;


    private JLabel bulletLabel;
    public static int y=90,dy=0,bulletX=110,bulletY,i=0,score=0;
    public static JLabel altitude = new JLabel();
    public static JLabel canFire = new JLabel("Blaster Charged: 100%");

    static boolean bulletFired=false, playing= false;
    static JFrame f = new JFrame();

    ADGame(){
        this.setBackground(Color.black);
        rocket = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("rocketFinal.png"));
        rocketlabel= new JLabel(rocket);
        this.add(rocketlabel);
        asteroid = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("asteroid.png"));
        ast1=new JLabel(asteroid);
        ast2=new JLabel(asteroid);
        ast3=new JLabel(asteroid);
        bullet = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("bulletReal.png"));
        bulletLabel = new JLabel(bullet);

        bulletLabel.setVisible(false);

        altitude.setBounds(270,285,200,20);
        altitude.setVisible(true);
        altitude.setForeground(Color.yellow);
        canFire.setBounds(350,285,200,20);
        canFire.setVisible(true);
        canFire.setForeground(Color.green);
        this.add(altitude);this.add(canFire);
         this.add(ast1);this.add(ast2);this.add(ast3);this.add(bulletLabel);

        f.addKeyListener(this);

        this.setLayout(null);
        this.setVisible(true);
    }



        @Override
        public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
            int keyCode = e.getKeyCode();


               if(keyCode== KeyEvent.VK_UP) {

                    dy=-1;

                   }
                if(keyCode== KeyEvent.VK_DOWN) {

                   dy=1;
                }
              if(keyCode== KeyEvent.VK_SPACE) {
                   if(bulletFired==false) {


                       bulletFired = true;

                       bulletY = y; 
                       bulletX=110;
                       }

              }
        }




        @Override
        public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
            int key = e.getKeyCode();

            switch(key) {
            case KeyEvent.VK_UP: dy=0; break;
            case KeyEvent.VK_DOWN: dy=0; break;

            }
        }

        @Override
        public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub


        }


    public static class StartScreen extends JPanel{
    public final Color screen = new Color(252,3,102);

    Font myfont = new Font("Helvetica", 1, 15);
    JButton start;
    JLabel AD, score;
    ImageIcon title,begin;
    StartScreen(){
        ImageIcon title = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("ADtitle.png"));
        JLabel AD = new JLabel(title);
        AD.setForeground(Color.yellow);
        AD.setBounds(0,-20,500,375);


        JButton start = new JButton("Start",title);
        start.setHorizontalTextPosition(JButton.CENTER);
        start.setVerticalTextPosition(JButton.CENTER);
        start.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(2, 8, 2, 8));
          start.setBounds(216,155,68,15);
        start.setFont(myfont);
           start.setBackground(this.getBackground());;
        start.setForeground(screen);
        start.addActionListener(new startListener());
    this.add(start);
        this.add(AD);

        this.setBackground(screen); 
            this.setVisible(true);
            this.setLayout(null);

        }


    public class startListener implements ActionListener{

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent a) {
            ADGame gamePanel = new ADGame();
            StartScreen StartScreen = new StartScreen();
            f.getContentPane().remove(StartScreen);
            f.getContentPane().add(gamePanel);
            f.validate();
            f.repaint();


        }

    }




    }   


    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        rocketlabel.setBounds(45,y,rocket.getIconWidth(),80);
        fireBullet();


        paintStars(g);
        t.start();
    }

    public void paintStars(Graphics g) {
        g.setColor(Color.yellow);
        for(int i=0; i<5;i++) {

            Random rand = new Random();
            int o = rand.nextInt(500);
            int p = rand.nextInt(300);
            g.fillOval(o, p, 3, 3);

        }
    }
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {


        if(y==-20) y=249;
        if(y==250)y=-20;
        y+=dy;
        if(bulletFired==true) {
            bulletX++;

            if(bulletX>455) {bulletFired=false;bulletLabel.setVisible(false);canFire.setText("Blaster Charged: 100%");canFire.setForeground(Color.green);}
            else {canFire.setText("Charging Blaster: "+String.valueOf(100*bulletX/445)+"%"); canFire.setForeground(Color.yellow);}

        }
        altitude.setText("Altitude: "+String.valueOf(335-y));


        repaint();
    }
    public void fireBullet(){
    if(bulletFired==true) {
        bulletLabel.setVisible(true);
        bulletLabel.setBounds(bulletX,bulletY+25,bullet.getIconHeight(),bullet.getIconWidth());
    }


    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String filepath = "SpaceGameMusic.wav";
        MusicLooper musicPlayer = new MusicLooper();

        musicPlayer.playMusic(filepath);
        ADGame gamePanel = new ADGame();
        StartScreen startt = new StartScreen();
        f.setTitle("Asteroid Defender");
f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

f.setSize(500,335);
f.setVisible(true);
f.setResizable(false);

    f.getContentPane().add(startt);



    }
}
```

I know it is messy, I started and just kept adding.

Comment: If you know your code is messy, spend some time cleaning it up (refactoring).  KeyBindings are much easier to use than KeyListeners.  Your JPanel possibly doesn't have focus, which disables a KeyListener.

Comment: what is focus on jpanels

Comment: JPanel focus: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2135223/obtaining-focus-on-a-jpanel